# codeigniter restful web service + database query

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, rest

Forgive me for the upcoming question, lol. (Im terribly new at this)

I have read  [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/) .

I've already set up the auto connect to database by editing the autoload.php file.

I'm creating my own controller called dsapi.php(code below), I want the `ad_get()` function  to retrieve all the data from my simple database so I can use it in the android app that I have developed.

I had a look at   [this guidelines page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html) and tried to write something but im pretty clueless as you can see. Am I even close to what I want?

```
class dsapi extends REST_Controller {

    function ad_get()
    {
        **$query = $this->db->query('SELECT index, title, detailed FROM ads');

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            echo $row['index'];
            echo $row['title'];
            echo $row['detailed'];
        }

        $this->response($query, 200);**
    }

    function ad_put()
    {
        // create a new user and respond with a status/errors
    }

    function ad_post()
    {
        // update an existing user and respond with a status/errors
    }

    function ad_delete()
    {
        // delete a user and respond with a status/errors
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do: `echo` values or return them? Your `ad_get()` does this: 1. retrieve the data, 2. `echo` that data, 3. return *query resource* (not the data!) as a response. I think you need to [separate command and query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[video tutorial](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/blog/)
[description of model](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)
and code example

```
 class Blogmodel extends CI_Model 
 {
 var $title   = '';
 var $content = '';
 var $date    = '';

 function __construct()
 {
     // Call the Model constructor
     parent::__construct();
 }

 function get_last_ten_entries()
 {
     $query = $this->db->get('entries', 10);
     return $query->result();
 }

 function insert_entry()
 {
     $this->title   = $_POST['title']; // please read the below note
     $this->content = $_POST['content'];
     $this->date    = time();

     $this->db->insert('entries', $this);
 }

 function update_entry()
 {
     $this->title   = $_POST['title'];
     $this->content = $_POST['content'];
     $this->date    = time();

     $this->db->update('entries', $this, array('id' => $_POST['id']));
 }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. Well ofcourse, how silly of me, I was missing a Model :D.